# Group by variation of 3 columns

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a table where I store R, G, B of each pixel of the image.

I would like to make a SELECT that grouped the results by the variation of these three columns respecting a margin.

I want for example that the record contains:
55, 100, 60 
is grouped with the record that contains:
50,105,65

In which case the change was defined as 5 more or less.

My goal is to return after the 7700 analysis pixels which variation of repeated color.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define "margin". A very simple answer would be

```
GROUP BY r/5, g/5, b/5
```

(assuming r, g and b are some form of integer as opposed to float or numeric)

You could do something fancier (maybe with window functions) if necessary.

Aside from that, I suggest creating a composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE pixel AS( r smallint, g smallint, b smallint);
```

And then you could store an entire image in a single row as a 2D array of pixel[]. For most things I'd expect that to be a bit easier. It should perform better too.